# Evidence based studies on the topic of best programming practices?

Tags: design-patterns, tdd, agile

When seeking advice on good programming practices the typical answers are a variation of agile software development, test driven development or design patterns. However, as far as I know, neither of these are proven using the scientific method (if I'm wrong on this then feel free to correct me).

I wonder, are there any good resources on the topic of evidence-based development practices?

Comment: Seems to be too broad, maybe you should be more specific about what practices are interesting to you. There are some empirical studies about agile. I do not think there is any real scientific proof about anything in software engineering, it just is not a science as e.g. math.

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't be possible. It seems doable, for example, to let one group solve an assignment using the old waterfall approach, and another group using an iterative approach. And later compare the results.

Comment: Yes, you could do that, and some people have on a small scale, but you'd have to do it with many groups in order to have any kind of statistical validity, as there are always other variables in play besides the methodology used.

Comment: & @donroby - not to mention the costs involved in actually conducting a suitable number of these experiments within industry. I'd like to see a PM explain to upper management that two parallel developments teams will be delivering late. One team because the initial scope contained a fundamental error, the other team because the design is a pile of s*#t. Perhaps a third team could be assembled to cobble both attempts together?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are really interested in this then the best source of information would be academic journals or the IEEE as donroby mentions.  If you have a degree from a uni and are an Alumni member still then you may be able access the information through the university library  (At least that is how it works in Australia. Alumni can get cheap membership to the library at the uni and access to a lot of the resources students use.)

EDIT:
Most of the information will not be experimental but studies of projects and surveys.  You can't really apply the scientific method in this kind of thing; it's closer to social science than it is the hard sciences like chemistry and physics

Comment: How is a survey not experimental? Do you think they test pain medication by hooking some measuring device to the patient or do they ask/survey how much does it hurt?

Comment: I am not going to start one of those debates sorry.

Answer (score 3):

There has been some research done on the impact of particular agile practices, but it is definitely sketchy.  There's likely a similar level of work with design patterns.

The links I'm putting here are by no means definitive, but have some value, and also reference other research that might be worth looking at.

- [An IBM and NCSU study on TDD](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.104.6319&rep=rep1&type=pdf)
- [A study on pair programming published in IEEE Transactions on Software Engineering](http://simula.no/research/se/publications/Arisholm.2006.2/simula_pdf_file)

Part of the value in reading these will be an understanding of how complex and difficult a question you have asked.

Really the most important evidence will be supplied by your own experience, should you be convinced to try some of these practices. It will also be difficult for you to quantify, but you might be able to decide whether the practices work for you.

Comment: +1 @donroby also important to note that just because it failed or worked for the person, doesn't mean it'll go the same in other projects or for other people. It takes a lot of experience + strong objective thinking, to reach valuable insights in these subjects.

Comment: @eglasius - Yes! More or less what I was trying to convey with "the most important evidence will be supplied by your own experience".

Answer (score 2):

The best comprehensive reference I know about software engineering scientific evidence is [Facts and Falacies of Software Engineering](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321117425). The book is concise, with refernces to the original sources (or it plainly says there are not), well-written, and not expensive.

The second best reference is [Code Complete](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670) but it is much longer, and it is not so focused on the evidence itself. It is nevertheless a must read book.

Once you have read these two books it is also worth looking on the "voice of evidence" series of articles from the IEEE Software magazine.